# Docker multi stage build with flask and postgressql

Tags: python, docker, flask, containers, devops

I've been trying to make the image of flask+postgresql smaller with docker multistage build, but its crashing because its not finding the flask app.py. Any idea why that is happening?

Error:

```sh
web_1  | Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
web_1  | 
web_1  | Error: The file/path provided (app.py) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
first-web-page_web_1 exited with code 2
```

Dockerfile that's not working:

```sh
FROM python:3.7-alpine as compile-image

RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY . .
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc musl-dev && pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.7-alpine AS build-image

COPY --from=compile-image /opt/venv /opt/venv

# Make sure we use the virtualenv:
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
CMD ["flask", "run"]
EXPOSE 5000
```

Dockerfile that's working that is not multistage:

```sh
FROM python:3.7-alpine as build
RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc musl-dev && pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM build
COPY --from=build /code .

ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
CMD ["flask", "run"]
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . /code/
```

Size of the working image is about 130Mb after its uploded to the registry is it even possible to make it smaller then that?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on here.

First, you would typically use two containers for this sort of project: one for the database, and one for the webapp. This comes with a few advantages:

- You can use the official `postgresql` image, rather than rolling your own
- You can upgrade one component without shutting down the other (a nice feature of you are making frequent changes to your web app but would like the database to just stay up and running)
- You can scale your webapp separately from the database
- You can rely on docker to restart a failed service

---

With respect to your question:

When you `COPY . .`, you're not copying your application into `/opt/venv`. It's going into the root directory, `/`. In your second stage, you do this:

```
COPY --from=compile-image /opt/venv /opt/venv
```

You never copy your app into the final image.

Secondly, when you this:

```
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc musl-dev && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You're not install your Python dependencies into your virtual environment, because you've never activated it.

I think you'd be better off using two separate images to start two separate containers (and then using something like `docker-compose` to manage your application stack).

Comment: The reason why I don't want to have 2 images is because i alredy have a posgress server thats runnung, my main focus is to lower the size of the docker image that has postgressql installend, but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: The first stage puts `/opt/venv/bin` at the front of `$PATH`, so it should run `/opt/venv/bin/pip` which will in fact install things into the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make the image smaller (from 140MiB ~ 24MiB) but not with multistage builds, just by removing the dependence that were needed for `postgresql` to be installed. If anyone has an idea why its not working with multistage I would appreciate it.

```sh
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN mkdir /code

ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0

ARG BUILD_DEPS="gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev"
ARG RUNTIME_DEPS="libpq"

WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build_deps ${BUILD_DEPS} && \
    apk add --no-cache ${RUNTIME_DEPS} && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
    apk del .build_deps 

CMD ["flask", "run"]
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . /code/
```